# How to get Hex String to Binary always in 8 bit formate?

Tags: java, android

I am converting Hex string to binary. It is working correctly. Below is my code. But i want out put in 8 bit formate.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String jhj = "1";
        int kj = Integer.parseInt(jhj);
        String kkk = Integer.toHexString(kj & 0xFF);

        System.out.println("Hex of String is: "+ Integer.decode(jhj));
        System.out.println("Binary of String Hex is: "+ hexToBin(jhj));
        System.out.println("Hex of Int is: "+ kkk);
        System.out.println("Binary of Int Hex is: "+ hexToBin(kkk));
    }

    private static String hexToBin(String s) {
        return new BigInteger(s, 16).toString(2);
    }
```

It is giving out put for Binary : 1
But i want it in 8-bit formate: 00000001

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`String#format()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) method, where you can specify the length of the output and denote you want it with leading zeros:

```
private static String hexToBin(Integer s) {
    return String.format("%08d", s);
}
```

and call it with:

```
System.out.println("Binary of Int Hex is: "+ hexToBin(kj));
```

Comment: private static String hexToBin(String s) {
  
  String str = new BigInteger(s, 16).toString(2);
  return String.format("%08d", str);
 }

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4045)
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Formatter.java:2748)
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2702)
 at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2488)
 at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2423)
 at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2790)
 at example.CheckSum.hexToBin(CheckSum.java:37)
 at example.CheckSum.main(CheckSum.java:27)